# Xamarin.Forms OnPropertyChanged executed multiple times in custom renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have faced with the issue that OnPropertyChanged handler executed multiple times in cutom renderer for the same property. I have created sample project to reproduce the issue. 
I have following form with TableView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IssueWithEvents"
                 xmlns:components="clr-namespace:IssueWithEvents.Components;assembly=IssueWithEvents"
                 x:Class="IssueWithEvents.MainPage">
      <TableView Intent="Form" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <TableRoot>
          <TableSection Title="Sample Form">
            <EntryCell Label="Item 1"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 2"></EntryCell>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Item 3"/>
                <components:CustomEntry x:Name="MyEntry" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding Counter}"></components:CustomEntry>
                <Button Text="Push" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"></Button>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 4"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 5"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 6"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 7"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 8"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 9"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 10"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 11"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 12"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 13"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 14"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 15"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 16"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 17"></EntryCell>
            <EntryCell Label="Item 18"></EntryCell>
          </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
      </TableView>
    </ContentPage>
```

Here is codebehind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IssueWithEvents
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public int Counter
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CounterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CounterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty CounterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Counter", typeof(int), typeof(MainPage), 0);

        private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button clicked");
            Counter++;
            MyEntry.SampleProperty = Counter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

One of the cell have custom layout with custom component inside. The CustomEntry component is just simple component derived from Entry with one additional property:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace IssueWithEvents.Components
{
    public class CustomEntry:Entry
    {

        private string _sampleProperty;

        public string SampleProperty
        {
            get { return _sampleProperty; }
            set
            {
                _sampleProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is renderer:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using IssueWithEvents.Components;
using IssueWithEvents.Droid.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace IssueWithEvents.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "SampleProperty")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SampleProperty Changed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just after run and pressing button the output in debug is ok:

```
[0:] Button clicked
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
```

Then if I scroll list so the custom cell disappear and then scroll it back and press button the output will be the following:

```
[0:] Button clicked
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
```

Each time you scroll custom cell out of screen and then scroll it back the number of event handler executions will grow:

```
[0:] Button clicked
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
[0:] SampleProperty Changed
```

I have spent few days to trying have solution for this issue but without success.
What I can find is that code that used for cell reuse is not dispose previous cell content properly and not unsubscribe from the onPropertyChanged event.
So it looks like bug, but maybe I am doing something wrong, or some one know ow to workaround this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you try to use `BindableProperty` for `SampleProperty`?

Comment: Just checked - the same issue. Actually 'OnElementPropertyChanged' called multiple times for all properties, not only for custom. I have changed little bit code in handler to log all properties and get the following output:  
`[0:] OnChangedCalled for Renderer
[0:] OnChangedCalled for Renderer  
[0:] Button clicked  
[0:] OnChangedCalled for Text  
[0:] OnChangedCalled for Text  
[0:] OnChangedCalled for SamplePropertyProperty  
[0:] OnChangedCalled for SamplePropertyProperty`

Comment: Did you try without the custom renderer first? What happens with the OnPropertyChanged of CustomEntry?